# Find/Replace a string within the Macro of Excel Files

Tags: vba, excel

So I have to go through several excel files and find/replace a string with the VBA code as well as in any data connections.  The loop for the connections is easy enough, but I don't know if there's a quick way for me to do it in the actual macro files themselves.  If I need to do this manually, that's fine, but I am hoping for a slick way of doing it.  Thoughts?

Comment: This might help: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: It did, I have been able to answer the question (posted below).

Comment: Nice work, glad the link helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of @Absinthe's article I was able to scrap together some code to answer my problem.

```
Public Sub MacroStringReplace()
    Dim x As Variant, SL As Long, EL As Long, SC As Long, EC As Long
    Dim OLD_STRING As String, NEW_STRING As String, foundString As String

    OLD_STRING = "Old"
    NEW_STRING = "New"

    With Workbooks.Open("C:\docs\foo.xlsm")
        'Macro Server String Replace
        For Each x In .VBProject.VBComponents
            SL = 1: EL = 1: SC = 1: EC = 1                'Default end line and column is 1
            'The find function here returns Boolean
            'SL will be the line number where the string was found (if at all)
            Do Until x.CodeModule.Find(OLD_STRING, SL, EL, SC, EC) = False
                foundString = x.CodeModule.Lines(SL, 1)   'Get the full line of code
                x.CodeModule.ReplaceLine SL, Replace(foundString, OLD_STRING, NEW_STRING)
                SL = 1: EL = 1: SC = 1: EC = 1            'Reset the search numbers
            Loop
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I hope this is helpful for others in the future.